# An error occurred when transforming the geometry to the SRID of the geometry form field

Tags: geometry, postgis, geodjango, srid

I am working on geodjango , postgis and found a problem while saving a location from OSMGeoAdmin with open street map .The map showing accordingly but when i want to save a location it shows with red error "An error occurred when transforming the geometry to the SRID of the geometry form field.".... 
please assist me .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Geodjango can not reproject your geometry, most likely because you forgot to install the PROJ.4 library. Read about geodjango dependencies in [the geodjango install docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/).